# TRIAC controlled fan voltage issue

Tags: voltage, triac

I have a question that seems to baffle electricians that I've spoken to.  I'm running a 115V Fan off a TRIAC controller that utilizes a 0-10VDC control signal.  When I power the DC control signal down, the fan stops running as expected.  However, when I take voltage readings at the fan terminal box I get 120V readings from Line/Ground and 120V from Neutral/Ground but zero volts from Line/Neutral.  Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: I'd guess that your controller is switching the Neutral line and therefore Live is always connected. Whether or not this is a good idea is a different question ...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a neutral to ground connection somewhere between your supply transformer and your building ...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzZekd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Switched neutral.*

It sounds as though the triac controller is in the neutral line.

> when I take voltage readings at the fan terminal box I get 120V readings from Line/Ground

That's the VM1 reading.

> and 120V from Neutral/Ground

That's VM3. The live feed is coming through the lamp filament.

> but zero volts from Line/Neutral.

That's VM2. The lamp is off and there is no voltage drop across it.

Answer (score 0):

1. pl. check the earthing (ground)..perhaps it is floating
2. Instead of checking voltage by voltmeter, pl. check the voltage by 240 V filament bulb..vtingole